# "Ambiguous routes matched" exception for nested pages in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I want to create app with three pages with routes:

- main
- main/card
- main/card/details

So I created MAUI App project and register pages in AppShell:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        Routing.RegisterRoute("main", typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("main/card", typeof(CardPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("main/card/details", typeof(DetailsPage));

        Items.Add(new ShellContent
        {
            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MainPage)),
            Title = "Main",
            Route = "main"
        });

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp3.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp3"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
</Shell>
```

MainPage has a button that goes to CardPage:

```
private async void GoToCard(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("card");
}
```

CardPage has a button that goes to DetailsPage:

```
private async void GoToDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("details");
}
```

DetailsPage has a button that goes back:

```
private async void GoBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}
```

GoToCard and GoToDetails work fine, but when I press GoBack, I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException
    HResult=0x80070057
    Message=Ambiguous routes matched for: //IMPL_main/IMPL_main/main/card matches found: //IMPL_main/IMPL_main/main/card,//IMPL_main/IMPL_main/main/card (Parameter 'uri')
    Source=Microsoft.Maui.Controls
    StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellUriHandler.GetNavigationRequest(Shell shell, Uri uri, Boolean enableRelativeShellRoutes, Boolean throwNavigationErrorAsException, ShellNavigationParameters shellNavigationParameters)
        at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.<GoToAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
        at MauiApp3.DetailsPage.<GoBack>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\Sources\MauiApp3\MauiApp3\DetailsPage.xaml.cs:line 12

    This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
        [External Code]
        MauiApp3.DetailsPage.GoBack(object, System.EventArgs) in DetailsPage.xaml.cs
```

Why am I getting this exception? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please avoid register the MainPage's route twice. I tried the following code and worked well:

```
    public AppShell()
    {
        Routing.RegisterRoute("main/card", typeof(CardPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("main/card/details", typeof(DetailsPage));

        Items.Add(new ShellContent
        {
            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MainPage)),
            Title = "Main",
            Route = "main"
        });

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I thought that adding an element to Items does not register the route., Thank you!